# C# Project Type not present in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2005

I have been coding using Visual Studio 2005, in VB.NET for a while.  No problems.

Recently, I decided I wanted to start a New C# project.  Upon attempting to do this, I noticed Visual Studio 2005 was missing this functionality entirely!

This is exactly what I get on my screen:

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://jongallant.googlepages.com/Untitled-1.png))</sub>

Also note that I have both Visual Studio 2003 and 2005 installed on the same machine.  Visual Studio 2003 has the C# templates available.

Any idea what I can do to solve this issue, without a re-install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you did not include C# durting the time of installation?  Restart the installation and add C# to it.

Comment: This is a work PC, I didn't do the install.  This is why I am hoping to fix it without having to get our microlan guys to fix it.  They are so damn slow to fix anything.

Comment: You need the installation CD. No need to reinstall. you just add to the existing one.

Comment: Yep, it was never installed.  I guess I was confused, as the templates directory was present.  After running the installer, it showed that C# was not installed.

Comment: Cool ;-) But honestly dint expect such a Q from a person with 1k+ rep until I saw your profile screen. I understand ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This might seem like a dumb question, but did you ever create a C# project with that version? In other words, did you install the C# personality? Because, you know, C# is not fundamental to Visual Studio ;)

You don't need to reinstall. If you are sure C# should be installed, just try Repair. If you didn't install it before, you can modify the installation. Takes much less time than a complete re-install.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to install C# when you install VS.

Also are you running a fill version of VS or express, the express editions contain only one technology.

From the screen shot I'd say you are running the full version as The express ones have a specific install for web stuff.

Reinstall VS and add C# to the list of things you want to install.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look there. I hope that help you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/4b09ba47-18d2-49a0-8cb7-7020706e034a/